# codeigniter : what is the best practice for caching?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm working on a big project. i'm using codeigniter, but i'm facing a hard question, where should i using codeigniter caching. should i use it inside models? or in the controller? also as my project is big, i'm facing a hard time trying to guess what caches should i delete as the codeigniter caching is depending on the controller name, so when i update a table i have to check all controllers that are using that table and delete their cache. that kills me.

what is the best practice for this?

Thanks

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. When your project actually starts getting very large you'll see where caching might be beneficial, trust me.

Comment: Not an answer, but take a look at this library for caching: http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/codeigniter-cache. What you need to cache depends a lot on what your application does. The default CI cache is not very useful... Well - it's not great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CodeIgniter have a good cache for small projects, but when you need to exclude things, it gets kind of messy. It's not decentralized.

A good solution for query cache is http://code.google.com/p/improved-query-caching/ and as Wesley told you, http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/codeigniter-cache.

I also don't recommend using the query cache for ALL your queries, but instead using the ones that really needs it. It depends a LOT in the project and its size.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that cache use only view. For example if you want to change language on the site it doesnt work because codeigniter will load old wiev with old language. And then you must wait untill new cache will be created and loaded with language which is currently set.